# Jersey 2.19 - JBoss EAP 6.2 - JBWEB000260: No servlet class has been specified for servlet

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to deploy a simple restful service in JBoss EAP 6.2 with Jersey 2.19.

Subclass of Application class:

```
package com.jersey.mywebapp;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(MyResource.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

RS Implementation class:

```
package com.jersey.mywebapp;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

My deployment descriptor:

```
..
    <servlet>
        <display-name>My JAX-RS Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>com.jersey.mywebapp.MyApp</servlet-name>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.jersey.mywebapp.MyApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.jersey.mywebapp.MyApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
...
```

Getting the below error while accessing the resource (localhost:8080/{context}/resources/myresource)

```
21:51:29,437 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web]. [default-host].[/rpa]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000264: Marking servlet  com.jersey.mywebapp.MyApp as unavailable
21:51:29,446 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rpa].[com.jersey.mywebapp.MyApp]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000235:    Allocate exception for servlet com.
jersey.mywebapp.MyApp: javax.servlet.ServletException: JBWEB000260: No servlet class has been specified for servlet com.jersey.mywebapp.MyApp
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1147) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:950) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:151) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780) [vm.jar:1.7.0]
```

As per my understanding JBoss EAP 6.2 supports Servlet 3.0 and as per Jersey documentation (Chapter 4. Application Deployment and Runtime Environments), Its valid to omit the servlet-class as per servlet pluggability mechanism.

Please advise on how to resolve this problem?

Note: To avoid/suppress RESTEasy from scanning for JAX RS resources i have commented out - subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0" from standalone.xml

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to use Jersey instead of the provided JAX-RS implementation, you may want to try this:
- restore the subsytem config for RESTEasy
- remove the web.xml servlet and servlet-mapping declarations in your application.

Since you provided a subclass of `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` with the `@ApplicationPath` annotation, there is no need for web.xml configuration (as per JAX-RS 1.1 spec, as I believe you mentionned above.)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this.. I would like to use jersey as i'm migrating an application in jersey(it uses some non-standard jersey specific features) to JBoss EAP 6.2. Also i tried your suggestion of removing servlet and servlet-class mapping from web.xml but it didnt work. Atlast configured servlet-class with <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> and got it working.